# Get calling method using StackTrace

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I have two scenarios where I want to know which is the caller method of some method I´m executing.

These are the scenarios:

1)

```
public static void ExecuteMethod(object obj)
{
    var mth = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
    string methodName = mth.Name;
}
```

And I call it this way:

```
public class Process
{
    public int Handle { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProcessID { get; set; }

    public dynamic GetOwner()
    {
        return WMIMethod.ExecuteMethod(this);
    }
}
```

When this is executed the result of `methodName` is the one I expect: `GetOwner`

The second and problematic scenario is this one:

2)

```
public static dynamic ExecuteMethod(object obj, dynamic parameters)
{
    var mth = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
    string methodName = mth.Name;
}
```

And I call it this way:

```
public class Process
{
    public int Handle { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProcessID { get; set; }

    public dynamic GetOwner(dynamic inParams)
    {
        return WMIMethod.ExecuteMethod(this, inParams);
    }
}
```

In this scenario, when I call `new Process().GetOwner(new { MyParam = "Something" } )` the result of `methodName` isn´t anymore what I would expect to be (`GetOwner`) and instead of that `methodName` is `CallSite.Target` and the result of `mth` is

```
{Void CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, System.Type, ORMi.Sample.Models.Printer, System.Object)}
```

Anyone knows why is the second case different of the first one??. How can this be solved???.

Thanks!.

Comment: Have you looked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: @dman2306 I was trying to avoid using because it forces me to add another parameter to the method... and I´m trying to make an easy to use library... this attribute usage even if it works... it is not as clean as the resilt that I get ftom StackTrace

Comment: is it possible one function is being inlined and therefore isnt on the stack?

Comment: @NicoRiff You can give the CallerMemberName parameter a default value, so that the caller or user of the method can ignore it as it will be set by the compiler anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've found is that when `dynamic` object is used, C# adds an additional method call `System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3()`.

In your case I'd rewrite the second method as

```
public static dynamic ExecuteMethod(object obj, dynamic p)
{
    var frame =
        new StackTrace().GetFrames()
                        .Skip(1) // Skip the 'ExecuteMethod'
                        .First(x => x.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Namespace != "System.Dynamic");

    return frame.GetMethod().Name;
}
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea why C# inserts that call, so I'll appreciate if someone can explain that internal work.

Comment: **A lot** goes into using `dynamic`. The *DLR* has to "spin up". It's sort of like the compiler is running again, at runtime. It caches information about each call site the first time so it doesn't have to necessarily recompile every time the code is called. I imagine that all of this 'voodoo' is done via extra method calls/delegate invocations that are inserted into the code by the *real* compiler. I'm sure if you decompile the code, they'd be evident (I admit I've never checked)

Comment: Thanks @Kyrylo It worked fine but I had to make a little adjust just to Skip 2 and not 1. It worked like this:   var frame = new StackTrace().GetFrames().Skip(2).First(x => x.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Namespace != "System.Dynamic");

Comment: @NicoRiff if you always pass `this` to the method, you can also utilize its type and filter using `x.GetMethod().DeclaringType`.